# Set size of imageview like fb app in android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, loading, facebook-apps

Do anyone know how to set imageview with some background before the image is loaded from backgroud like that of one found in fb app for android?

In fb android app, the image view are set before image is loaded of same size as that of the image.

Comment: that would be adownload proeprty.You ar ebasically trying to retrieve the meta data before your image downloads..have you tried doing that?

Comment: i have downloaded the url of the image .Then using picasso or imageloader, url is loaded into imageview.

Answer (score 0):

I just converted drawable into bitmap of same size as that of image . Then i displayed that bitmap before loading the image from url.